# Compiling PHP with MySQL 5.5

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compile php 5.3.6 with mysql 5.5.4. The error I get is:

```
checking for MSSQL support via FreeTDS... no
checking for MySQL support... yes
checking for specified location of the MySQL UNIX socket... no
checking for mysql_close in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for mysql_error in -lmysqlclient... no
configure: error: mysql configure failed. Please check config.log for more information.
```

This is the end of the config.log file:

```
configure:59920: gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -L/usr/lib64  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/kerberos/lib64 -L/usr/kerberos/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/root/imap-2006h/c-client -L/root/imap-2006h/c$
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: failed program was:
#line 59909 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
/* Override any gcc2 internal prototype to avoid an error.  */
/* We use char because int might match the return type of a gcc2
    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
char mysql_close();

int main() {
mysql_close()
; return 0; }                 
configure:60143: checking for mysql_error in -lmysqlclient
configure:60162: gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -L/usr/lib64  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/kerberos/lib64 -L/usr/kerberos/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/root/imap-2006h/c-client -L/root/imap-2006h/c$
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient                  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: failed program was:
#line 60151 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
/* Override any gcc2 internal prototype to avoid an error.  */
/* We use char because int might match the return type of a gcc2
    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
char mysql_error();            

int main() {      
mysql_error()
; return 0; }
```

The php config file is:

```
    #! /bin/sh
#
# Created by configure

'./configure' \
'--with-libdir=lib64' \
'--with-mysql=/usr' \
'--with-gd' \
'--with-zlib' \
'--with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib' \
'--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib' \
'--with-png-dir' \
'--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local' \
'--enable-sockets' \
'--enable-sigchild' \
'--enable-pcntl' \
'--enable-soap' \
'--with-kerberos' \
'--with-curl' \
'--with-imap=/root/imap-2006h' \
'--with-imap-ssl' \
"$@"
```

I have installed the client and development libraries. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the mysqlclient library? I don't think it'd be in `/usr` as your configure output shows.

Comment: It's in /usr/lib64. The config file specifies libdir=lib64. I changed it to /usr/lib64 and it found it. Thanks for the hint.